# create a boost::posix_time::ptime instance for X number of milliseconds

Tags: c++, linux, boost

```
boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::named_recursive_mutex>
```

when creating an instance, i need to use the

```
scoped_lock(mutex_type & m, const boost::posix_time::ptime & abs_time);
```

constructor.
how can i create a scoped_lock for X number of miliseconds ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If **X** is milliseconds you want to spend while waiting for lock acquirance then this snippet should help you:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime till = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() + 
    boost::posix_time::milliseconds(X);
...
{
    boost::interprocess::scoped_lock(some_mutex, till);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Keynslug, thanks a lot. except the change from boost::ptime to boost::posix_time all is working fine. thanks a lot

Comment: My bad, @Oded, thanks for pointing out, i've corrected namespaces.